# Programmatically set property based on other properties in a custom entity

Tags: 8, entities

I created a custom entity and want to programmatically set the title based on 2 other properties.

For example, the entity has `year` and `state` properties. When the entity is created, I want to populate the `title` property with `year state`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try [hook_entity_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.4.x) or if only on creation hook_entity_insert().

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since I created this entity myself, it really seems like this should be achieved in the entity source, vs the module. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a custom entity type, you can override [`EntityStorage::doPreSave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AdoPreSave/8.2.x) in your entity class:

```
function doPreSave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  parent::doPreSave();

  // Perform field manipulation here.

  return $entity->id();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just before I saw this, I got `public function preSave(EntityStorageInterface $storage)` to work. I went back and tried your suggestion though and the changed property would not save. I'm unsure what the difference between `doPreSave` and `preSave` is.

Comment: It depends - `preSave` is called (by `doPreSave` as it happens) _before_ `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave` is invoked. If that's the flow you need, use `preSave`. If you'd rather run your presave code after all other modules have got involved via the hook, use `doPreSave` and run the parent method before your own code